# Format JSON text using jansson in C

Tags: c, json, jansson

So I'm trying to format text in a desired fashion using the received JSON string in server side. My code is using jansson library to parse JSON.

Here is the input JSON string (will be received from client):

```
{"system": {"hmiSettings": {"wifi": {"destIp": "192.168.10.150", "port": 5501}, "bluetooth": {"destMac": "00:00:00:00:00:00", "uuid": "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00601F4C34AC"}}}}
```

Here is the desired output, it can be put in a char buffer or a file:

```
system:hmiSettings:wifi:destIp "192.168.10.150"
system:hmiSettings:wifi:port 5500
system:hmiSettings:bluetooth:destMac "00:00:00:00:00:00"
system:hmiSettings:bluetooth:uuid "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00601F4C34AC"
```

Here is the sample code snippet I found for parsing JSON string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <jansson.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_json(json_t *root);
void print_json_aux(json_t *element, int indent);
void print_json_indent(int indent);
const char *json_plural(int count);
void print_json_object(json_t *element, int indent);
void print_json_array(json_t *element, int indent);
void print_json_string(json_t *element, int indent);
void print_json_integer(json_t *element, int indent);
void print_json_real(json_t *element, int indent);
void print_json_true(json_t *element, int indent);
void print_json_false(json_t *element, int indent);
void print_json_null(json_t *element, int indent);

void print_json(json_t *root) {
    print_json_aux(root, 0);
}

void print_json_aux(json_t *element, int indent) {
    switch (json_typeof(element)) {
    case JSON_OBJECT:
        print_json_object(element, indent);
        break;
    case JSON_ARRAY:
        print_json_array(element, indent);
        break;
    case JSON_STRING:
        print_json_string(element, indent);
        break;
    case JSON_INTEGER:
        print_json_integer(element, indent);
        break;
    case JSON_REAL:
        print_json_real(element, indent);
        break;
    case JSON_TRUE:
        print_json_true(element, indent);
        break;
    case JSON_FALSE:
        print_json_false(element, indent);
        break;
    case JSON_NULL:
        print_json_null(element, indent);
        break;
    default:
        fprintf(stderr, "unrecognized JSON type %d\n", json_typeof(element));
    }
}

void print_json_indent(int indent) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < indent; i++) { putchar(' '); }
}

const char *json_plural(int count) {
    return count == 1 ? "" : "s";
}

void print_json_object(json_t *element, int indent) {
    size_t size;
    const char *key;
    json_t *value;

    print_json_indent(indent);
    size = json_object_size(element);

    printf("JSON Object of %ld pair%s:\n", size, json_plural(size));
    json_object_foreach(element, key, value) {
        print_json_indent(indent + 2);
        printf("JSON Key: \"%s\"\n", key);
        print_json_aux(value, indent + 2);
    }

}

void print_json_array(json_t *element, int indent) {
    size_t i;
    size_t size = json_array_size(element);
    print_json_indent(indent);

    printf("JSON Array of %ld element%s:\n", size, json_plural(size));
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        print_json_aux(json_array_get(element, i), indent + 2);
    }
}

void print_json_string(json_t *element, int indent) {
    print_json_indent(indent);
    printf("JSON String: \"%s\"\n", json_string_value(element));
}

void print_json_integer(json_t *element, int indent) {
    print_json_indent(indent);
    printf("JSON Integer: \"%" JSON_INTEGER_FORMAT "\"\n", json_integer_value(element));
}

void print_json_real(json_t *element, int indent) {
    print_json_indent(indent);
    printf("JSON Real: %f\n", json_real_value(element));
}

void print_json_true(json_t *element, int indent) {
    (void)element;
    print_json_indent(indent);
    printf("JSON True\n");
}

void print_json_false(json_t *element, int indent) {
    (void)element;
    print_json_indent(indent);
    printf("JSON False\n");
}

void print_json_null(json_t *element, int indent) {
    (void)element;
    print_json_indent(indent);
    printf("JSON Null\n");
}

/*
 * Parse text into a JSON object. If text is valid JSON, returns a
 * json_t structure, otherwise prints and error and returns null.
 */
json_t *load_json(const char *text) {
    json_t *root;
    json_error_t error;

    root = json_loads(text, 0, &error);

    if (root) {
        return root;
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "json error on line %d: %s\n", error.line, error.text);
        return (json_t *)0;
    }
}

/*
 * Print a prompt and return (by reference) a null-terminated line of
 * text.  Returns NULL on eof or some error.
 */
char *read_line(char *line, int max_chars) {
    printf("Type some JSON > ");
    fflush(stdout);
    return fgets(line, max_chars, stdin);
}

/*
 * main
 */

#define MAX_CHARS 4096

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char line[MAX_CHARS];

    if (argc != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s\n", argv[0]);
        exit(-1);
    }

    while (read_line(line, MAX_CHARS) != (char *)NULL) {

        /* parse text into JSON structure */
        json_t *root = load_json(line);

        if (root) {
            /* print and release the JSON structure */
            print_json(root);
            json_dump_file(root, "tmpJ", 0644);
            json_decref(root);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Can someone help me out creating the output in the above mentioned format.

Comment: What have you tried so far? have you tried to modify the sample code, and if so do you have any specific questions about your modifications?

Comment: Yes, I tried modifying functions print_json_array(), print_json_string() print_json_aux() to print in the format I have mentioned. But the problem comes when one JSON object instance is completed.

Comment: Instead of indenting the output you need to keep copies of the previous prefixes. Please tell us your specific problem and show us your code.

Comment: "The problem comes..." Which problem? What happens and what did you expect? How did you modify the snippet?

Comment: Yes, I tried modifying functions print_json_array(), print_json_string() print_json_aux() to print in the format I have mentioned. But the problem comes when one JSON object instance is completed. For instance, after printing \nsystem:hmiSettings:wifi:destIp "192.168.10.150"\nsystem:hmiSettings:port 5501\n I need bluetooth nodes ie. system:hmiSettings:bluetooth:<node> value\n. This means I need to hold "system:hmiSettings:" in some temporary buffer. Is there a simpler way to do that?

Comment: Could you please add your problem description to the question instead of comment? And of course the modified code, not the initial snippet you found.

Comment: Why not use existing JSON parsers? - [there are plenty](https://github.com/miloyip/nativejson-benchmark). The [facil.io library](http://facil.io) (edge version) has an integrated JSON parser and dynamic type system which you could probably use see the [foij.h](https://github.com/boazsegev/facil.io/blob/ab73f34ba9919a9ebb7a352ce875ceb8152cf1ba/lib/facil/core/types/fiobj.h) header and [sources](https://github.com/boazsegev/facil.io/tree/ab73f34ba9919a9ebb7a352ce875ceb8152cf1ba/lib/facil/core/types/fiobj).